# Floor() on the result of a division

Tags: php

Given the calculation: (14056567/(14056567/100)) , this equals a float of 100.
Using PHP floor() on a float of 100, should always return 100.

But here is my problem: floor() returns 99 when the input float 100 is the result of a division.

Test 1:

```
<?php
$test = (14056567/(14056567/100));
var_dump($test);
$test = floor($test);
var_dump($test);

// output:
// float(100)
// float(99)
```

Test 2:

```
<?php
$test = (14056567/(14056567/100));
$test = (double)$test;
$test = (float)$test;
$test = floatval($test);
$test = 0 + $test;
var_dump($test);
$test = floor($test);
var_dump($test);

// output:
// float(100)
// float(99)
```

Test 3:

```
<?php
$test = (14056567/(14056567/100));
$test = floatval('' . $test);
var_dump($test);
$test = floor($test);
var_dump($test);

// output:
// float(100)
// float(100)
```

So only when concatenating a string and my float, it gives my expected result after a floor().

According to the response in the following link: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=6851
The reason is that 100 equals 99.999999 in floats, even if that is true, why is this not the case when it is not a result of a division?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 14056567/100 = 140565.67
```

Is fine to humans because we work in decimal, computers work in binary, and .67 isn't exactly easily represented in binary(and I'm not even 100% sure it's possible to exactly represent that figure, even with perfect precision).

If you generate the hex for it the result is something like `0.ab851eb851eb88`, but `0.ab851eb851eb88` is actually a number around `0.670,000,000,02`.

When you do your division by this approximation you get a number that's best represented as 100, but is actually something more like `99.999,999,999,98`, which to display when you call `var_dump` is rounded off.

When you call floor it gives you exactly 99 because that's what `floor(99.9999999)` actually should generate, the answer of 100 was the result of rounding, the result of floor is correct for the number you're using.

Comment: I just wanted to point out, that 140565.67 can be precisely represented in binary, only not by using IEEE 754. But as any conversion from binary to decimal is a convention made up by humans, you can easily represent number 140565.67 with only one bit, by saying, that if bit has value 1, that means decimal value 140565.67, otherwise the value is undefined. It just won't get standardized, because it is not very useful :)

Comment: I always loved math but it never loved me lol - **+1** for a well-written/explained answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following script to see whats going on:

```
<?php

printf ("# No precision lost\n");
printf ("14056567.0 = %.53f\n\n", 14056567.0);

printf ("# No precision lost\n");
printf ("100.0 = %.53f\n\n", 100.0);

printf ("# Precision lost, because 140565.67 can't be represented precisely in float\n");
printf ("14056567.0/100.0 = %.53f\n\n", 14056567.0 / 100.0);

printf ("# Same here without division\n");
printf ("140565.67 = %.53f\n\n", 140565.67);

printf ("# Lost precision carrying on...\n");
printf ("14056567.0/140565.67 = %.53f\n\n", 14056567.0 / 140565.67);

printf ("# This is OK\n");
printf ("14056567.0*100.0/14056567.0 = %.53f\n\n", 14056567.0 * 100.0 / 14056567.0);

// Output:
// # No precision lost
// 14056567.0 = 14056567.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
// 
// # No precision lost
// 100.0 = 100.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
// 
// # Precision lost, because 140565.67 can't be represented precisely in float
// 14056567.0/100.0 = 140565.67000000001280568540096282958984375000000000000000000
// 
// # Same here without division
// 140565.67 = 140565.67000000001280568540096282958984375000000000000000000
// 
// # Lost precision carrying on...
// 14056567.0/140565.67 = 99.99999999999998578914528479799628257751464843750000000
// 
// # This is OK
// 14056567.0*100.0/14056567.0 = 100.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

?>
```